# Getting SQL results in parts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I know i can limit the count of received results using the `TOP` keyword, but is there a way to receive the next let say 1000 results using something like `<give me the next 1000 results>` which gives me each time the next cached 1000 ones?

So assume my query has 100000 and the first run i get 1-1000 i would like to receive the 1000-2000 and so on.

Comment: What is the reason for this? Based on your tags it seems for optimization. But can you explain more about this? I am leary of this type of approach, especially using something like `ROW_NUMBER()` as suggested in the answers, because `ROW_NUMBER()` is _dynamically_ generated, which means that it's very possible for small changes in the underlying datasource to throw your entire process off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
SELECT 
    col1, 
    col2 
FROM 
(
     SELECT 
         col1, 
         col2, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RowNum
     FROM 
        MyTable
) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE 
    MyDerivedTable.RowNum BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

Answer (score 5):

When the data is changing between queries, rownum/between solutions will give you approximations of the next chunk of data.

If you need to get a specific chunk of data from a fixed result, insert all of the results into a table and then consume the data as needed. The results will stay fixed until you refresh the data in the table again.

This works well when you must get the exact next set (forward or backward). This might be useful, depending on your situation.

Comment: +1 for the warning about the data changing between queries with ROW_NUMBER().

Answer (score 1):

Suppose there is following table

```
create table #temp
(
    ID int Identity(1,1) ,
    name varchar(1000)
)
```

Suppose there are following records in the table

```
select * from #temp
```

[image: Total records]

We starts with declaring following variables

`Declare @PageIndex INT` //indicates the start index that means your page number

`Declare @PageSize INT` //the total amount of records you want to display in a page

```
Set @PageIndex = 1
Set @PageSize = 10
```

I am setting the page size = 10 because I have only 15 records in my table . But you can replace this number by 1000 or even greater than this number.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
        AS Row, * FROM #temp
)T WHERE Row between 
(@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1 and @PageIndex*@PageSize
```

If you execute the below query it will give you following records in the screen shot.

[image: Result from query]

While moving to second page using below query.

```
Declare @PageIndex INT
Declare @PageSize INT

set @PageIndex = 2
set @PageSize = 10

SELECT * FROM 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
   AS Row, * FROM #temp
)T WHERE Row between 
(@PageIndex - 1) * @PageSize + 1 and @PageIndex*@PageSize
```

The result will be below in the screen shot.

[image]

So similarly you can check  with 1000 records.

Hope this will help you.

Let me know in case of any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to order your data as desired in a subquery or [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx). Then select from that subquery/CTE with the desired values (e.g., `WHERE RowNum > 1000 AND RowNum <= 2000`).